# Run Javascript function only on a particular item with same class name

Tags: javascript, function

Without using jQuery, how can I run a function only on one item that has the same class names as the other items?

I have a WordPress loop with each item has a button to run a function on an image in the div.

Here is the loop item that repeats 10 times on the page:

```
 <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
     <div class="block bg-white relative mt-7 work__image-wrap">
       <a href='<?php echo types_render_field("website-url"); ?>' target="_blank">
        <?php echo '<img class="item absolute pin-t w-full h-auto pin-l" src="'. $workitem .'" alt="'. the_title() .'"/>';?>
       </a>
      </div>
       <div class="button-wrap">
        <button id="portScroll">Scroll Down</button>
       </div>
       <div class="p-2">
        <h3 class="text-black font-bold pt-4 pb-2"><a class="text-black font-bold" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
       </div>
    </li>
```

When the user clicks the button the function changes the CSS so that it scrolls up.

How do I run the function only on the item in the loop?

Here is my JS to run the function. It works fine on the first loop item but not the others.

```
function scrollDown() {
    var portImg = document.getElementById('item');
    var height = portImg.clientHeight;
    console.log(height);
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos == height) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos--;
            portImg.style.top = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your current function cannot work correctly, as there is no element with `id="item"`. Also your HTML will have multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by "*only on the item in the loop*" - there are multiple items generated by the loop, right?

Comment: Why do you mention jQuery? Do you know how you would solve this with jQuery?

Comment: Do not want to use Jquery and want to save people's time from answering using jQuery. There are multiple items in the loop.

Comment: Is it customary here to update my question with the working code or leave it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the button's `id` attribute with a `class`:

```
<button class="portScroll">Scroll Down</button>
```

Define the button click handlers like this:

```
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('button.portScroll')) {
    button.addEventListener("click", scrollDown);
}
```

In the function `scrollDown` get the image as follows:

```
var portImg = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('img.item');
```

Or, alternatively:

```
var portImg = this.closest('li').querySelector('img.item');
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. Thanks for the JS lesson!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do (Simplified of course):

```js
(function(){
  const posts = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
  for(let i = 0, m = posts.length; i < m; i++){
    const buttonElement = posts[i].getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0];
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', handleButton);
  }
  function handleButton(e){
    scrollDown(e.target.dataset.postId);
  }
  function scrollDown(item) {
    var portImg = document.getElementById('post-image-' + item);
    console.log(portImg);
    var height = portImg.clientHeight;
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos == height) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos--;
            portImg.style.top = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}
})();
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <img id="post-image-199">
  <button data-post-id="199">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img id="post-image-195">
  <button data-post-id="195">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img id="post-image-198">
  <button data-post-id="198">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great answer but i want to stay away from having to use IDs so this can be applied to any type of loop. Thank you!